# Did Denmark reduce their need for hospitals by two-thirds?

Tags: medical-science, denmark

Dave Chase, CEO of Avado, made this claim in a [TechCrunch article](http://techcrunch.com/2011/07/31/healthcare-disruption-healthcare-providers-repeating-newspaper-industry-mistakes-part-iii/):

> Prevention-focused countries such as Denmark have dramatically lowered the need for hospitals. Once at 155 hospitals, they are at less than a third of that today. I find this easily-known fact is news to healthcare providers I speak with.

I find it quite astonishing, but unfortunately he provides no evidence for the claim in the article.

**Has Denmark reduced the number of its hospitals from 155 to less than 51?**

If so, has the demand reduced by a similar amount? (I'm just trying to figure out if there are any catches, like each remaining hospital has grown by a factor of three, waiting lists have blown out, the definition of hospital has changed, etc.)

(I'm not asking for proof of the cause of the reduction; even if it turns out the reduction is caused by measures such as banning Facebook on hospital firewalls, I would still be impressed with that health result.)

Comment: Consolidation of small hospitals into big hospitals has surely happened over the last decades. The interesting question is whether the number of hospital beds went up or down.

Comment: @chr I was going to say the same thing.

Comment: @Christian, yeah, I suggested that may have been what happened - that's why I asked about "demand". Hospital beds is somewhat of a proxy for that. That said if, for example, surgeries are less intrusive these days, and patients get out faster, that means less beds are required to meet the same demand.

Comment: Determining the demand for hospital beds is tricky. Hospital beds demand patients. They are not like hotel beds where you sometimes have a hotel that is half empty.

Comment: @OT: in a socialised healthcare system demand doesn't dictate availability. Beds get added or scrapped based on some bureaucrat's decision. If there's fewer beds than demands, waiting lists grow longer. That's what's happening all over Europe. One effect is that people die waiting, causing the number of procedures to drop. Another is that people simply don't even try to get medical care (or pay private for it in another country, Spain is popular for many Europeans because of its high standard medical facilities and relativly low cost), causing the number of procedures to drop.

Comment: @jrwenting, if you have some references that waiting lists in Denmark have grown and are causing more deaths, please make it an answer. In the meantime, the only correlation I see with socialised healthcare [seems to go the other way](http://www.commonwealthfund.org/Content/Publications/Issue-Briefs/2011/Jul/US-Health-System-in-Perspective.aspx).

Comment: I can say that under the current Venstre administration that some 'wait times' have increased, however there is legislation in place which limits that wait for 'acute' cases (cancer, etc).  If someone with a cancer diagnosis waits more than 4 weeks (if I recall correctly), then they're allowed to go to a private hospital for treatment on the state's dime.  Also, while the number of 'state' hospitals might have declined, I do believe the number of 'private' hospitals has increased.  I'll have to check on the #'s, but there has been a political scandal regarding the hospitals out ehre in DK.

Comment: @OT that was a generic answer about socialised healthcare systems that anyone who lives under them can vouch. Being told you have to wait 6 months for "critical surgery" says it all (my mother was told that once), being told you're "lucky someone on the list died and you were pushed up over others" is commonplace here. If you have to wait 6 months for life saving procedures, when the average person getting that diagnosis has 3 months to live, you do the math as to the survival rates.

Comment: Another consideration worth consideration is the notion that increasing access to preventative care may improve outcomes for patients that detect conditions early, but from a financial point of view it tends to INCREASE total spending on healthcare because the cost of screening far more people does not offset the cost savings of earlier treatment of major medical issues, which while expensive only apply to a very small number of patients.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Once at 155 hospitals, they are at less than a third of that today.

A third of 155 is 51.67 - hence the statement implies that there are 51 or fewer hospitals.

Wikipedia provides [a list of hospitals in Denmark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hospitals_in_Denmark). By my count, there are 89 in the list.

89 is more than 51. 89 is 57% of 155. If there really were 155 hospitals at some point (which I haven't confirmed) a more accurate statement would be "they have reduced that by more than a third today."

Potential sources of error in this analysis include:

- I relied somewhat on Wikipedia. I followed up a couple of its sources ([e.g.](http://www.regionh.dk/NR/rdonlyres/16B2E22E-46A0-4F41-915C-D8B37A13751E/0/H%C3%98RINGSVERSION_ForslagtilHospitalsogPsykiatriplan2020_23marts.pdf)), and did some spot-checks to confirm the hospitals still existed, and found no errors. I may easily have missed some that, for example, have since closed down. **Update:** Thanks to the help of @Darwy (see comments), it seems the Wikipedia site over-estimates the number of hospitals by around 6. This weakens this argument significantly, but doesn't invalidate it.
- I relied on translation tools and some very rusty Swedish language skills to read the Danish hospital documents and web-sites. I may have misunderstood some details.
- It isn't clear that the original definition of hospital that got a count of 155 is the same definition used by the Wikipedia authors. It could be that the initial definition was stricter (e.g. not including psychiatric hospitals), and would exclude some of those 89.

Comment: I know that Wiki link isn't exactly up to date for private hospitals, there's one that's 1.5 km up the road from where I live, yet not listed on the site.  It's a small private hospital, so they might have excluded the ones with less than "X" number of beds, etc.

Comment: @Darwy! You speak Danish? Yay! Could you spot-check a few more of the Wikipedia hospitals to confirm they really exist, pretty please? If some are missing from the Wikipedia list, that doesn't hurt my argument, but if a significant number of those present have since closed, it invalidates it.

Comment: There's currently a HUGE restructuring of the hospitals and service areas in Denmark.  For example, the hospital where I had my son no longer has a maternity wing; it's been moved 15 km to a different hospital, etc.

Comment: Comparing just the Region Sjælland Wiki:

Fakse, Korsør, Nakskov, Nykøbing Sjælland has been closed. Holbæk, Kalundborg, Køge, Nykøbing Falster, Næstved, Ringsted, Roskilde og Slagelse are still open.

Source: http://www.regionsjaelland.dk/regionens-opgaver/sygehuse/findsygehus/Sider/Findditsygehus.aspx

Comment: Greater Copenhagen Area Hospitals (includes Bornhølm out under Sweden): Skt Hans Hospital is no longer listed, and the Wiki page lacks the Helsingør Hospital.  Apparently Skt Hans is purely a psychiatric hospital, might be why it's no longer listed as a general hospital anymore.
Source: http://www.regionh.dk/menu/sundhedOghospitaler/Hospitaler2/Hospitalernes+hjemmesider.htm?WBCMODE=http%253a%252f%25252_blan

Comment: Midtjylland hospitals: Brædstrup has merged with Horsens. Kjellerup and Odder are no longer open. The rest seem to be the same. Source: http://www.regionmidtjylland.dk/kontakt/hospitaler? The Wiki hospitals for Nordjylland are correct.

Comment: Syddanmark: The Brørup hospital has been closed, then reopened and is in use for medical purposes but is no longer a hospital, per se.  Other than that, the rest of the list looks good.

Comment: Not a problem; glad I could help out! Also remember; some of the hospitals on that list are psychiatric hospitals and not general hospitals.

Comment: I think he either jumbled on words or was misquoted... What he meant to say, or originally said could be "Once at 155 hospitals, they are a third less than that today."

Comment: @Oddthinking The number "155" appears in US War Department Technical Bulletin 52, Medical and Sanitary Data on Denmark.  There were 155 hospitals with a total of 24,056 beds, as of 31 December 1939.   https://books.google.com/books?id=yxMTAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22general+hospitals%2C+with+bed+capacity%2C+of+denmark%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=155

Comment: 1939! Even though these were general hospitals, this makes a mockery of the original claim! There has been a lot more than prevention that kept people out of hospitals since then.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I might get someone questioning this data so I asked the source (an American MD who leads one of the major tech/software projects over there but is US-based) who is very knowledgeable of the Denmark success story. Here was his verbatim response... "the average number of days went down, the number of beds went down in percent even more than hospital . This is happening today in Geisinger and Kaiser as well with PCMH [my note: PCMH = patient centered medical home] level care better upstream care, care coordination of chronic disease, lower downstream need for beds. In addition this is impacted by ambulatory surgery and a program like that tried by Advocate in Chicago of hospital at home with remote monitoring and video conference-ing. this is our future for sure much safer, less wasteful but the key is the hospital bed is seen as a failure and is a cost center not a profit center.

in the USA the average length of stay is 6.7 days -- Denmark 3.9. Cost per hospital stay in Denmark $6,700 in the USA $19,456. We have to use dialyze twice as often. but with higher mortality rates and lower life expectance for the disease that require dialyze for example.

[Ref: [*Widespread Adoption of Information Technology in Primary Care Physician Offices in Denmark: A Case Study*](http://www.commonwealthfund.org/~/media/Files/Publications/Issue%20Brief/2010/Mar/1379_Protti_widespread_adoption_IT_primary_care_Denmark_intl_ib.pdf), Denis Protti and Ib Johansen, Issues in International Health Policy, March 2010]

There's an interesting parallel with Deming's work with the auto industry. An American idea gets ignored by Americans so it's taken abroad and implemented with gusto. In Deming's case, Toyota et al embraced it and then it took Detroit 30+ years to catch up. Likewise, the PCMH concept originated in the US in 1967 and Denmark adopted it. 40+ years later, Denmark is spending far less and getting far more and we (Americans) are playing catchup.

As Ben Franklin said, "an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure." It certainly applies to medicine. In the US, it's a shame to say that it's more lucrative for a MD to amputate a diabetics leg than it is to care for him in his chronic condition and avoid that from ever needing to happen.

Comment: You need to cite your sources for this answer. Who is the doctor? Why should his opinion carry so much weight? As it stands this is an appeal to authority. I'd also suggest linking to where we can see the PDF you reference somewhere online.

Comment: Note: I've inferred the reference from the filename provided by Dave Chase, and edited it in.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, for coming to Skeptics.SE to respond to the claim. It's great to hear from the original proponent. I've read what your (anonymous) doctor friend has written, and also the report on the IT situation in doctor's offices. Neither seems to touch on the claim that Denmark has reduced its hospitals from 155 to less than 1/3 of that.

Comment: Can't find a reference to "PCMH" in the linked article. Isn't a PCMH just a hospital in disguise? And if it focuses on the less severe/further recovered patients, its costs per patient will be lower. Such differences make international comparisons harder.